# SVG <image> doesn't work in <defs> on Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, svg, rendering

I want to use image in a group definded in defs tag. But on Chrome nothing works. In Firefox only the .png file is displayd. Only Rectangle apears but with strange bug in Chrome. Is this is supported by SVG or im not using it right.

plane.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg  baseProfile="full" width="500" height="500"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

 <defs>
  <g id="car">
   <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" fill="#ff0000" />
   <image xlink:href="items/car.svg" x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" />
   <image xlink:href="items/t6k.png" x="100" y="100" width="140" height="140" />
  </g>
 </defs>

 <use xlink:href="#car" x="0" y="0" width="600" height="600" />

</svg>
```

images/car.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg  baseProfile="full" width="30" height="30"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

    <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="30" fill="red" stroke="green" stroke-width="3"/>

</svg>
```

Download code: http://www.4shared.com/file/9gNi5gCO/svg_bug.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like valid SVG 1.1 to me. I think Firefox doesn't yet support svg in the `<image>` element. My epiphany-webkit nightly seemed to render it fine though, and Opera too.

**2014 update**: external svg <image> works fine in Chrome, Opera and Firefox, see [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/structure/external-image.svg).

Comment: I can confirm that Firefox, including FF4b6, does not support svg in the image element.